# For $a,b,c>0$. Minimize $P=a+b+c$

Tags: maxima-minima

For $a,b,c>0$ and $\frac{2}{a}+\frac{5}{b}+\frac{3}{c}=1$, minimize $$P=a+b+c$$

Comment: Lagrange's multipliers seem the way to go.

Comment: we should start with...?

Comment: ... Lagrange's multipliers.

Comment: can you use other way ?

Comment: Obviously $a>2,b>5,c>3$.So we found one The minimum value of P is greater than 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Cauchy Schwarz:
$$
1\times P=\left(\frac{2}{a}+\frac{5}{b}+\frac{3}{c}\right)(a+b+c)\geq(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3})^2
$$
so $\min P=(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3})^2$ when
$$
\frac{2}{a^2}=\frac{5}{b^2}=\frac{3}{c^2}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{2}{a}+\frac{5}{b}+\frac{3}{c}=1;
$$
i.e. 
$$
a=2+\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{10},\quad b=5+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{15},\quad c=3+\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{15}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\frac2a,y=\frac5b,z=\frac3c.$
$$\min P=\min\left(\left\{\left.\frac2x+\frac5y+\frac3{1-x-y}\,\right|\,x,y>0,x+y<1\right\}\right)$$
is attained at the critical point,
$$x=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5},\quad y=\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5},$$
hence its value is
$$2\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5}{\sqrt2}+5\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5}{\sqrt5}+3\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5}{\sqrt3}$$
$$=(\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt5)^2.$$